# Add Roles or Claims to User created via Google OAuth2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth, asp.net-identity

We have implemented Google OAuth2, and it creates users in the ASPNetUsers table. This works fine, and we can see the authenticated user via User.Identity.GetUserName().

If we add this user to a role, say "MyCustomRole", via AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles table, any methods secured with:

```
[Authorize(Roles="MyCustomRole")]
```

cannot be accessed. The application forwards the authenticated user to the Login controller.

What is the proper mechanism for adding these externally-authenticated users to Roles, the having those Roles accessible for the [Authorize(Roles="")] attribute?

Comment: It turns out that I was using the Id rather than the Name, in the filter. So, instead of [Authorize(Roles="MY_ROLE_ID")], it needed to simply be [Authorize(Roles="MyRole")]. It is nice, and quite simple, to be able to add roles to users authenticated by external systems via OAuth2, simply by adding the row to AspNetUserRoles as you would with any other kind of user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of `asp identity` your are using but I accomplish what you want using this code

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddUserToRole()
    {
     var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
 new[]{"YourCustomRole"});
    if (!result.Succeeded){ 
       return View();
    }
   else{
       return RedirectToAction("index");
     }
   }
```

To test this you may need to create an empty project, an empty! then run this nuget in newget package 
`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre`
then you may put my action code in the `UsersAdmin` contoller